# What, besides the MX record, do I need to enter into my DNS zone for my mail server?

Tags: email, smtp

When I test my mail server on https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/, it is able to retrieve the MX record, but then fails with this:

> Attempting to resolve the host name mail.mysite.org in DNS. The host name couldn't be resolved.

Do I need to setup another record besides MX for a mail server?

Comment: If you provide the actual domain name, it will be more useful in trying to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have an address (A) record for your mail server so that it can be resolved to an IP address.  Or a CNAME record pointing to a valid address record.  Without this nothing will be able to figure out how to contact your mail server.